# Twisted Matrix, hooking custom class to event loop

Tags: python, twisted, twisted.internet

Trying to build a twisted application that will receive messages on multiple ports. The ports should generate `Alert` objects which amongst other things have a `tag` property and a `trigger` property. The app should then check to see if there is already an `AlertJob` with that tag. If there is it should just enqueue the `Alert` to that `AlertJob` and if not it should first create the new `AlertJob`. The `AlertJob`'s ... job is to periodically check the trigger and if trigger conditions are met, to notify the main app again. And here is my question:

How can I hook a custom class (`AlertJob`) into twisted's reactor so that it continuously verify's if trigger conditions are met for any of the running jobs ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your application calls for a time-based event source, then `twisted.internet.reactor.callLater` or `twisted.internet.task.LoopingCall` is probably what you're looking for.  These are both covered in the [scheduling howto](http://twistedmatrix.com/documents/current/core/howto/time.html).